# microsoft-adal-angular6 Token Refresh Error

Tags: adal.js, microsoft-adal-angular6

I'm using Angular ADAL wrapper microsoft-adal-angular6 in my application. Authentication is working. however, during token refresh, Azure AD returns "A silent sign-in request was sent but none of the currently signed in user(s) match the requested login hint" error. is there any fix for this issue?

This is the trace from the fiddler.
REQUEST HEADER
`GET /xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/#/login/callback#&state=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx|xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&client-request-id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.17&prompt=none&login_hint=Firstname.Lastname@comapany.com&domain_hint=company.com&nonce=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx HTTP/1.1`

RESPONSE
`Location: http://localhost:4200/#error=login_required&error_description=AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but none of the currently signed in user(s) match the requested login hint. Trace ID: 81dc661a-9151-4d18-a951-e202aa411b00 Correlation ID: ce35413a-f1fa-44ef-aa48-937375c579cc Timestamp: 2020-07-01 11:23:35Z&error_uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50058&state=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx|xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`

I tried adalsvc.RefreshToken() to avoid the silent sign-in (is that correct?) and I got the below warning.
`Set-Cookie header is ignored in response from url: https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/#/login/callback#&state=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx|xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&client-request-id=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=1.0.17&prompt=none&login_hint=firstname.lastname@company.com&domain_hint=company.com&nonce=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx. Cookie length should be less than or equal to 4096 characters.`

Comment: Can you please share full error details

Comment: Thanks. I've added more details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possible for causing the error

**Possible Resolution #1** Proactively Check for Expiration
You can attempt to prevent this error from ever occurring by checking if you have a valid id token. If you're ID token is not valid, you will ask the user to login again.

**Possible Resolution #2** Catching the Error and Asking the User to Login Again
To resolve this error you will need to catch this error in a callback that you can pass into the acquiretoken ADAL JS function. If the AADSTS50058 error occurs, you'll ask the user to login again.

**Possible Resolution #3** Browser Extension Cookie Blockers and Third Party Cookies Disabled
Some users may experience this issue due to a browser extension that is blocking cookies for tracking purposes. This will cause this AADSTS50058 error to occur, you will need to whitelist the login.microsoftonline.com endpoint in your browser extension in order to avoid receiving this error again.

This error can also occur if the third party cookies have been disabled in your browser. Re-enable third party cookies in your browser to prevent this error from occurring.

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaddevsup/receiving-error-aadsts50058-in-javascript-setting)

Please choose MSAL over ADAL and here is the sample  for [angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/)  using MSAL

Please refer the link for [migration of ADAL to MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration)

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_9N5Udp7UFcbexLf&Q_CHL=gl
>